# How can I extract and then change the url path using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, path

I am trying to extract part of the url and replace it with custom text using javascript.

For example, I want to fetch the current url such as:
`mydomain.com/url_part_to_change/some-other-stuff`

and then change that url to insert so that new new url is:
`mydomain.com/new_url_part/some-other-stuff`

Here is what I have:

```
function changeURL() {
        var theURL = window.location.pathname;
        theURL.replace("/url_part_to_change/", "/new_url_part/");
        //Set URL
}
```

However, when I try to call the function `changeURL()`, it returns `undefined` instead of the new url.

---

For example if I do this:

```
alert(changeURL());
```

then what alerts is `undefined`

Comment: How and where are you calling changeURL()? You are not returning anything.

Comment: @sdfasdf acdsgcxzg I think you missed the `return` statement, without that functions do not return anything, just compute

Comment: @CrissLion lyon: yes, thank you, please tell me how to fix. I tried adding `return;` after `//set URL` but it still returns `undefined`. Edit: I just saw your answer, thank you! I will try.

Comment: better to put complete code here

Comment: not needed, correct answer was already given.

Comment: added examples and links to uri components below if interested for readings

Comment: deleted kjakjajsjhaj?

Comment: tried to delete, doesn't allow, had to add 15 char

Comment: If you want to disassociate yourself from this question, flag it for moderator attention explaining what and why. Don't simply deface your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not returning any thing in function, Please make function like

```
function changeURL() {
        var theURL = window.location.pathname;
       return  theURL.replace("/url_part_to_change/", "/new_url_part/");
        //Set URL

}
```

Comment: this answer is wrong as it just returns the original url not the new one.

Comment: ok Sorry for that you need new variable to return that or simply return it, but while answering this i was more focused on undefined error, will edit it right away

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DR

```
// update the pathname that will reload the page
window.location.pathname = myNewPathname;
```

---

**Further Explanation:**

[Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) ( image attached below ) provides you an object containing all the uri parts information. So, you can get this object via `window.location` and access the property `pathname` then do your stuffs. For example:

```
var locationObject = window.location;
var pathnameToChange = locationObject.pathname;

// do stuffs to "copy" of pathname, this will not reload the page
var myNewPathname = doSomethingMyPathname( pathnameToChange );
```

**Additional Examples:**

Alternatively, set new url using `location.href`. Check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) for examples on `location.assign()`, `location.replace()`, `location.reload()` and notes on the different available functions

```
// ie.myNewUrl is something I created -> www.blah.com/updated/path
window.location.href = myNewUrl; 

// or
window.location.assign(myNewUrl)
```

**A window.location Object in Console**

[image: window.location]

There are three references to further understand URI components

1. [URI_scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)
2. [Standards written by Tim Berners-Lee](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)
3. [MDN Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm, seems a bit much, others address the issue directly when you are just posting a bunch of stuff that it too confusing.

Comment: ah, the first part was a direct answer, next few parts are for understanding and also references. it may help you or others, perhaps i should have made it clear.. ill add that TLDR; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you correctly:

```
function changeURL() {
        // Get the url, just as you did
        var theURL = window.location.pathname;
        // Return the url
        return theURL.replace("/url_part_to_change/", "/new_url_part/"); 
}
```

Comment: Just for educational purpose - if you need to match url parts that could have variable content like user name, you could use regular expressions! RegEx is one of the topics people avoid, but is really useful [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [playground](http://www.regexr.com/) It allows you to match strings that would be a complete pain matching with basic string functions.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, you don't return anything. What they are forgetting is that String.replace() just makes a copy of `theURL` and doesn't change `theURL`.

Try this:

```
function changeURL() {
  var theURL = window.location.pathname;
  theURL = theURL.replace("/url_part_to_change/", "new_url_part/");
  //Set URL

  return theURL;
}
alert(changeURL());
```

Comment: I forgot to change the url that I used at JsFiddle. I edited the above post to include the correct url "/url_part_to_change/"

Comment: still nope, look at Criss Lion's answer to see what you did wrong. your answer just returns the original answer instead of the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return`

```
function changeURL() {
    var theURL = window.location.pathname;
    var newURL = theURL.replace("/url_part_to_change/", "/new_url_part/");
    //Set URL
    return newURL;
}

alert(changeURL())//Now you won't see undefined.
```

Comment: This returns original URL not the changed one.

Comment: yes this would work also it looks like. But Criss Lion gave a correct answer first. Thank you for your answer as this also seems correct. Too bad I can't choose two best answers?! :)

Comment: i would upvote as you requested but upvote requires 15 rep and since someone downvoted my question I am back to 0 rep :( I tried to upvote, if that is any consolance :'(

Answer (score 0):

```
   function changeURL() {
      //set new path
      window.location.pathname = "/new_url_part/";

      //get new url
      const newURL = window.location.href;
      return newURL;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: the assignment to pathname will change the url, making the last two lines superfluous

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old post but just to add:

modifying window.location causes page navigations so if thats not desired create a new URL object and then you can modify the parts as needed.

in my case i needed to change the path to a value from a value in the querystring.

eg.

```js
/*
 * http://something.com/some/path?redirect=/some/other/path
 * ->
 * http://something.com/some/other/path
 */

let u = new URL(window.location.href)
u.pathname=u.searchParams.get("redirect")
u.searchParams.delete("redirect")
console.log(u.href)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [URL Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) is probably the best tool for the job.

```js
let urlString = "http://example.com:8080/url_part_to_change/some-other-stuff";
let url = new URL(urlString);
let path = url.pathname;
let base = url.href.replace(path,"");

let pathArray = path.split("/");
pathArray.forEach(function(p, i){
 console.log(i, p)
});
pathArray[1] = "new";

console.log(base + pathArray.join("/"));
```