# Javascript redirection not working in Flask

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a flask website and am trying to make a search bar that is always on the top menù, I would have liked to handle it in the Python backend but I could not find a way to do that without including whithin each backed page the code to handle it (which if it is the only way is fine) so I decided to try making it work with JavaScript. This is my code (without the parts which I found unrelated to the problem):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="search" id="searchbar"/>
<button id="goto">Search</button>
</form>
<script>
            document.getElementById("goto").addEventListener("click", goTo);
            function goTo()
            {
                var result = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;
                window.location.href = "/users/"+result;
            }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What it is supposed to do is redirect me to "http://myip/users/WhatItyped" while it just adds "/?" to the end of the URL, any idea of why this is?

Update: I found out that if I add an alert before defining result it works

Answer (score 1):

Try using `window.location.pathname`

[JavaScript Window Location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) states `href` points to the full URL, including protocol & hostname. Since you are not changing either of those, you can just change the relative path from the root using `pathname`.

This has also been answered before:
[How can I extract and then change the url path using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137059/how-can-i-extract-and-then-change-the-url-path-using-javascript)

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work but I did find out the problem is correlated with the form tag I put on it which stupidly I did not use in the code here, removing it this worked. Is there any way to make this work with the form tag? Thanks for the help!

Comment: i copied your code above, made my change, & it worked in Firefox, so I'm not sure why it didn't work for you